# Android Listview

Tags: android, listview

**i want to Differentiate Listview and perform different action in different position.**

This is my Code.

```
    al.add(new Student("हनुमान चालीसा", "Hanuman Chalisa", R.drawable.omicon, R.drawable.ic_file_download));
    al.add(new Student("श्री बजरंग बाण", "Shri Bajrang Baan", R.drawable.omicon, R.drawable.ic_file_download));
    al.add(new Student("संकटमोचन हनुमानाष्टक", "Sankatmochan Hanumanashtak", R.drawable.omicon, R.drawable.ic_file_download));
    al.add(new Student("श्री हनुमानजी की आरती", "Hamuan Je Ke Arti", R.drawable.omicon, R.drawable.ic_file_download));
    al.add(new Student("हनुमान जन्म कथा", "Hanuman Janam Katha", R.drawable.omicon, R.drawable.ic_file_download));

    adapter = new StudentAdapter();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.i(getTag(), "onListItemClick: " + position);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click To Play/Download Iocn", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });



    return singleview;
```

Comment: Show the code of `StudentAdapter` then ?

Comment: post full code or your implementation

Comment: you maybe getting  position in this line Log.i(getTag(), "onListItemClick: " + position);  so what's wrong?

Comment: In  setOnItemClickListener  you getting position,  then what is problem?

Comment: @ShubhamShukla bro i want to perform action on listview not same action in different position

Comment: you have to perform action on whole listview clisk not an item click?

Comment: You can perform action on different position by use of state manage in Student class. so that you can identify which one action to perform, can get object of Student  class.

Comment: can you please send me a Whole Code please.

Comment: You're already getting a position of the clicked item in onItemClick(), so you can use switch(position) inside that function and do whatever action you want. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @MatveyRybakov hello dude can you please help i want to download song from listview click with service can you plese help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use switch statement

```
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.i(getTag(), "onListItemClick: " + position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Click To Play/Download Iocn", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               Switch (position){
                  case 0:  
                      //do whatever in 0th position
                  break;
                  case 1:  
                      //do whatever in first position
                  break;
                  ..
                  ...
                      //like this use other positions}


        }
    });
```